# PowerChute for VMware ESX4

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I am looking for a free way of installing PowerChute for VMWare.  The 2.2.3 and 2.2.4 Linux versions do not support VMWare ESX even though I think prior versions did.

APC is now charging $100 for the install CD which I think is a joke considering the price of our Symmetra UPS.  VMWare support should be free.

**Edit:** I see someone voted this question to be closed, so to be clear i am looking for a free and **legal** way of getting PowerChute support for VMWare, by either using an older version or a custom script.

Comment: Any luck here yet.  Would be great to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ghettoUPSHostShutdown.pl](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-11902)

You need [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.com) to monitor the UPS, [VMware vMA 4.0](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vima/) (apcupsd and perl script run on this VM), and licensed ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download both the Powerchute Business edition, and the powerchute network shutdown installs from APC's site for free. [This is the link](http://www.apc.com/tools/download/software_comp.cfm?sw_sku=SFPCNS223&id=127&swfam=127)  to the network shutdown component.

Comment: Your link goes to the standard APC download page.  None of the listed downloads support VMWare ESX.  I have tried using th Linux one and you can install it but the configuration tool gives you a message stating "VMWare is not supported"

Comment: Interesting, thier documentation shows that 2.2.3 will work on vmware 
http://nam-en.apc.com/cgi-bin/nam_en.cfg/php/enduser/fattach_adp.php?p_sid=0&p_tbl=9&p_id=9920&p_faqid=9920&p_created=1256130774

look at the screen shots - says 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Zypher - Please see this page http://blog.mwpreston.net/?s=poweroff. He has a great write up and some powerCLI which I've used in a couple of environments. Might require a bit of tweaking to get to do exactly as you want but hasn't let me down yet.