# Shutting down ESXi on Battery Backup

Tags: vmware-esxi, scripting, ups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PowerChute for VMware ESX4](https://serverfault.com/questions/85512/powerchute-for-vmware-esx4)

I came into an issue where I have an APC that doesn't have a network shutdown card in it. I figured I can map the USB connection over to one of my hosts, install the software, and if there is a power outage, use the run script feature to shutdown any servers I need with the `shutdown` command.

My question: Is there a command I can run to shut down the ESXi hardware? And if not, is there an issue with not shutting down the actual ESXi hardware if the battery runs out and it is just turned off?

Comment: Unless APC has a plugin specifically for ESXi, I doubt the APC software will be installable. If you can hook it up via USB to a different machine, however, you could issue the shutdown command from there. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1013193

Answer (score 1):

You can use the perl or powershell API to send a shutdown command to an ESXi box (via a vCenter server) from just about any host.

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/index.html
http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/