# How do I inform my ESXi 5 host(s) of a power outage?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, ups, electrical-power

My APC UPSs all have the APC SNMP card so they are able to communicate over the network. From what I've been able to find the PowerChute program alerts the guest OS that a power outage has occurred but not a VM host. I'd rather alert the host (or vCenter) so vCenter can manage the power.

I honestly don't know if vCenter can do what I want it to do (with Enterprise licenses) but what I'd like to have happen is this:

1. Shutdown non-essential VMs.
2. Migrate essential VMs to as few hosts as possible. (In my case I have only two.)
3. Power down the unused host.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://serverfault.com/questions/85512/powerchute-for-vmware-esx4/154538#154538

Comment: Honestly I didn't see that question while I wrote up my own though I did check out a few others that looked positive. In any case I'll check out the solutions offered there as well.

Answer (score 3):

APC provides the software [Powerchute Network Shutdown](http://www.apc.com/products/family/?id=127&ISOCountryCode=hk) for this usage, where you install the agent on the [vSphere Management Assistant](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vima/) as it's no longer possible to install software directly on ESXi.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure if the Powerchute software can shut down machines according to priorities etc, but I remember the MGE software (also on a vMA) could do it. Give it a go and see what happens!

Comment: Looks very promising. It may take me a while to test though.

Comment: Revisiting this. In 2013, how should this be done?

Comment: @ewwhite this hasn't changed, you still use the vMA